# What does it mean when folders/files are grey in Netbeans 10?

Tags: netbeans, ide

As you can see in the screenshot, some folders/files are colored grey.  What does it mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files and folders are not under version control.

Whereas the others are part of your git repository (assuming you are using git because of the `gitignore` file)

Answer (score 0):

grey for ignored files, 
review options>misc >files